# Random default inline styles for html input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I am developing a full-stack MERN application and I have come across something strange when viewing my React UI in Chrome DevTools.

In case any of these are a factor, there are a few dependencies I have installed that could be contributing to this issue:

- Tailwind CSS
- Material UI (only icons but @material-ui/core is installed too)

Here is some of my code:

```js
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

const initialState = { name: '' };

function reducer(state, { field, value }) {
  return {
    ...state,
    [field]: value
  };
}

export default ProfileForm() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const handleChange = e =>
    dispatch({ field: e.target.name, value: e.target.value });

  const { name } = state;

  return (
    <input
      className='placeholder-gray-400 text-teal-500 outline-none'
      type='text'
      name='name'
      id='name'
      placeholder='Your Name'
      value={name}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  )
```

The className string values refer to tailwindcss classes. This input is a controlled component via Reactjs useReducer hook. I am not using useState because I have many other input fields that need to be controlled as well.

When I view this component in the browser with Chrome DevTools, this shows:

```html
<input
  class="placeholder-gray-400 p-2 outline-none"
  type="email"
  name="email"
  id="email"
  placeholder="Email"
  value=""
  style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;">
```

For some reason this weird style property is being applied. It's happening on most of my input elements but not all. I cannot find any difference between the ones that have it and the ones that don't. Maybe this isn't anything serious, but I would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: please elaborate on "this weird style property is being applied." - what is being rendered and how should it be rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be a password manager extension that adds the following icon to your input.

[image]

Can you disable all your extension and see if that changes it?

Comment: Or you may test it in incognito mode or another browser.

Comment: Yes, Incognito would be a good option as well. I didn't want to assume that the password manager is disabled in incognito.